Should I unify the two methods?
I am working with WinForms. In one of the forms I have two combos that are filled through a method that brings the data from the database.
In another method, I have two other combos that are filled with the same data and a method that is an exact copy of the method I have in the first form.
Is it correct to think that I should have only one method for both? Trying to do this I established how I publish the method of form1 so that I can instantiate it from form2 but in form2 it does not bring the data. Can you advise me?
Form1 h = new Form1()
h.LoadCombo()

thank you!!

A UserControl is an obvious approach.
